# Parsing string use regex

Tags: regex, robotframework

I have some string

```
022/03/17 05:53:40.376949    1245680 029 DSA- DREP COLS log debug S 1
```

Need get 1245680 number use regex statement
I use next regular `\d+` but many result in output.

Comment: There are a lot of different ways of doing this. e.g. specify the number of digits you want (e.g. "\d{7}"), use capture groups (e.g. "   (\d+) "), use lookahead "?=" or lookbehind "?<=". It would probably help to do some general reading or find a tutorial on regexes to get started.

Comment: Use `\b\d{7}\b`, look [here](https://regex101.com/r/mkFl6n/1).

Comment: I don`t use d{7} because this value can be from 0 to 9999999 and have different number of digits

Comment: Then how do you know which number to extract?

Comment: I think use '(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}[.]\d{6})'  to find  '05:53:40.376949' and catch next value

Comment: If this is a fixed string, you can just grab all of the characters between the timestamp and "029" - no need to use regular expressions. Is there a specific reason you want to use regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

First: are you sure that you want to have regex? Wouldn't a string cut operation be better?

First for a fixed amount of 29 characters as this is the prefix length and then search for the next space in the rest of the string to clear the remainder.

If you have to use regex for some other reason (e.g. you don't have the ability to implement a routine where you need it), you can use a regex with a group to extract just the number you want: `^.{29}(\d+).*$`

Here you have to use group(1) or any other reference to a group in the language you are using to get the value you want.

As the rest of the line also can contain numbers (and I suppose a variable amount of characters, if this a log entry), my simple attempts to use lookbehind and lookahead combination failed as they also found that other numbers in the line.

Comment: I use robot framework to parsing log and my test key need get value from string.

Comment: I'm not familiar with robot framework, but if you expect a specific number, you can replace the part `(\d+)` with just the number you expect, so the regex would be for your specific example: `^.{29}1245680.*$` - this means, that number 1245680 has to be in the string starting at position 30 and can be followed by anything. You can add spaces before and after, if you want to be sure that it's not part of another number, but if you add a space before, you have to decrement the number in the curly braces (to `{28}`)

Comment: Or if you want to match any number between 0 and 9999999 you can use `\d{1,7}` - this will match 1 to 7 digits (but also would allow for leading zeros like 0000000) or use `(?:[1-9]\d{0,6})|0` to match only values without leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If  `022/03/17 05:53:40.376949` is always in that format, you can use:

```
\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{1,6}\s*(\d*)\s*
```

or more generally:

```
\d*\/\d*\/\d*\s+.*?\s+(\d*)
```

These will match the date/time segment, whitespace, the sequence of (captured) digits you desire, and then more whitespace.